# Get notification fields

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm making an accessibility service that includes notifications, I was wondering if it's possible to get the icon bitmap and "details" of the notifications, I know that the tickertext can provide the "title of the notification" but I would like to access the line that show the "details text" formerly the "getText" method of the contentview field of the notification.

Comment: Really nobody is interested in this aswell? :O

Comment: Do you create the notifications yourself?? I suppose not.

Comment: Noup, third-party notifications

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get more details and even reconstruct the `Notification` object.  I haven't tested this, but it should work fine.

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
...
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
        Parcelable parcelable = event.getParcelableData();
        if (parcelable instanceof Notification) {
            // Resource id within the package context of the notifying app.
            int icon = ((Notification) parcelable).icon;
            Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(event.getPackageName());
            Drawable image = res.getDrawable(icon);
        }
    }
}
```